# Display Data in a Grid view -MFC c++ dialog based application

Tags: c++, mfc, modal-dialog

By receiving data from excel file , I have developed MFC c++ application. I populated four combo boxes based on data in excel file. By selecting the combo boxes I want to  show rest of the data in excel file below the combo boxes. **For data visualization **,

1. What are the available data visualization grids ?( all the data after the visualization can be accessed easily)
2. Are there possibility to use excel grid  view (just like ruler based data grid view)[Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ktozg.png) to display rest of data in the selected excel file.

Comment: You are asking for a library or a way to do something, that is offtopic. Use Google and search for Grid and MFC... you will find several grids. Also there are libraries you can buy like the BCG-Lib and others. And you can surely use the list view, if this is enough for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a ListView control with report-style. See:

- [List View Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774737(v=vs.85).aspx) and the MFC classes
- [CListCtrl Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfshke78.aspx)
- [CListView Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3ch0w2y.aspx)

Also, you can use [Chris Maunder's MFC Grid control](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8/MFC-Grid-control-2-27)